# Gazebo - joints control in position

Tags: control, ros, gazebo, services, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys!

I'm new of gazebo world. I've build a little arm with 3 links and 2 joints. With the user interface i can assign a forse to a joint or a position too (in degree for example). I cannot find a way to do the same thing by the topics or services (i need to set position but i've find just this service: gazebo/apply_joint_effort  but this don't help me)

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49439/gazebo---joints-control-in-position/) by [pacifica](https://answers.ros.org/users/1187/pacifica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on 2012-11-29**:
which version of ros/gazebo are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How about creating a plugin, where you can access the joints and apply forces on them?
[Here is a plugin example.](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/plugins)

One possibility for getting the joint and applying a force on it would be something like:

physics::ModelPtr my_model = _parent;

physics::JointPtr my_joint = my_model->GetJoint("name_of_joint");

my_joint->SetForce(0, 3.0);

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [Andrei Haidu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1419/andrei-haidu/) with karma: 146 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1